# How to remove my website link when adding a link?

Tags: urls

I'm trying to add links to social media pages on my WordPress website. However, when I add the icon and the link to the social media page and save it, the link automatically adds my website.

Example: `www.example.com/www.facebook.com/examplepage`

I don't understand how my domain name is added before the link even though I haven't added it.

Any help, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to include the protocol ([scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax)), like `https://`. So for Facebook it would be `https://www.facebook.com/examplepage`.

It is in this case not WordPress that adds your site URL in front of the URL, it's your browser!

Answer (score -1):

I hope you have solved your problem by now, but if not I might have the answer.  I was having the same problem and when I looked at my code I saw that I had used (”) quotation mark rather than (") quotation mark.  After I changed the code to (") quotation mark everything worked perfect.

a href=”www.mywebsite.com” → http://www.mywebsite.com/www.mywebsite.com

a href="www.mywebsite.com" → http://www.mywebsite.com/